# ¿Para un viaje a Guatemala tengo que aprender a conjugar con "vos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, voseo, guatemala

Voy a viajar a Guatemala en unos meses, ¿Necesito aprender cómo conjugar en la forma "vos" antes de irme? ¿No puedo ir solo sabiendo "tú?"

Answer (score 7):

En Guatamala existe una triple distinción entre *vos*, *tú*, y *usted*.  Aunque si fueses a vivir allí sería plenamente recomendable aprender el voseo tal y como se emplea en Guatemala, la verdad es que, especialmente dado que el tuteo se considera más formal que el voseo (pero no tan formal como el trato de *usted*), tutear sin vosear no te va a ocasionar ningún problema, sobre todo como extranjero (e incluso en países como Argentina donde no hay triple distinción, por ser extranjero, no va a haber ningún problema).

Digo lo de arriba sin tener experiencia personal en Guatemala, pero sería la recomendación general para cualquier viajero a un país voseante.  Lo único que notaría es que según la Wikipedia, el tuteo entre dos hombres en Guatemala se percibe algo afeminado, y se evita.  Pero dudo que los guatemaltecos, al escuchar un hombre extranjero que tutea, vayan a juzgarlo de la misma forma que a un guatemalteco.

Pero si quieres, y especialmente si no eres nativo, diría que intentes aprender el voseo, que es una de las riquezas de la lengua menos enseñadas en clases de castellano.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta que da @guifa me parece muy válida. Entre más inmersa estes en las costumbres del lugar al que vas, supongo que mejor será la experiencia y el proceso de adaptación.

Ahora, si tengo que dar una respuesta directa a tu pregunta

> ¿Para un viaje a Guatemala tengo que aprender a conjugar con “vos”?

Mi respuesta es no, no tienes que hacerlo. Si tienes un dominio aceptable del "usted" o del "tú" te van a entender perfectamente. Es decir, si deseas aprender a usar el "vos" está muy bien, pero si no lo haces eso no te va a impedir la comunicación, y nadie esperaría de ti (de un extranjero, en general) que lo domines.

Como caso particular, yo vivo en Colombia, donde coexisten las tres formas: "usted", "vos" y "tú". En unas regiones se usan una de las tres, o dos o todas; en distintas medidas y circunstancias. Yo sé usar las tres, pero solo estoy acostumbrado a usar el "usted" y el "tú”. Nunca he usado el "vos" ni lo uso ahora que vivo en una ciudad donde prevalece esa forma. La razón: no me impide la comunicación y no me sentiría "natural" usarlo.

Mi recomendación: no lo fuerces. No estás incurriendo en errores del lenguaje, diría que es más cultural. Si con el tiempo terminas usándolo que sea porque lo vas adoptando naturalmente.

Comment: mmm...según esto, estas viviendo en _paisalandia_ Espero lo estes pasando bien. (Saludos desde Medellín) ....jejeje.

Comment: @DGaleano Saludos desde Cali :). Yo nacido en el Valle pero con familia antioqueña. ¡Quizá de allí la mezcla!

Answer (score 3):

Yo soy española y como tal no uso nunca el "vos", sólo el "tú" para situaciones informales y el "usted" para situaciones formales. Pero sí que sé conjugarlo.

Sin embargo, si fuera a Guatemala tengo muy claro que no cambiaría mi forma de hablar :) no habrá problemas de comunicación y los de allí en seguida deducirían que no soy guatemalteca, por mi acento, y llegarían a la conclusión de que es mi forma de hablar habitual.

Igualmente, si un guatemalteco me habla con el "vos", en seguida notaría el acento diferente, y supondría que esa es su forma de hablar habitual, y no esperaría que él cambiase al "tú". No impide la comunicación en ningún caso.

En conclusión, aunque no sé de dónde eres, creo que no hablas español de forma nativa, así que esto es todavía más justificable. Usa el pronombre que mejor domines, porque te conseguirás comunicar con cualquiera de los tres, en el país hispano-hablante que sea.